# What is this second AC filter from duct entering the return?

Tags: hvac, filter

AC novice question. There is a second black filter behind my AC return filter. It looks like this filters air entering the return from a second duct. However, this duct looks like it's nearly completely sealed off with a circular object blocking the flow before the air reaches the filter. What is the purpose of this black filter? I can't seem to find a replacement anywhere. These were very dirty but I rinsed them and they look almost new but not sure if the media is too used and spread out to actually function properly. Can I just reinstall after they dry? Pics in the link below.

https://imgur.com/a/yuTrgFZ

Comment: are you talking about the mesh wire

Answer (score 1):

The blue square is reusable filter material.

It supposedly can be rinsed , dried and reused. However it does have a usable life span. Replacement filters are available in large 24 to 30 inch sizes and you have to cut it to the size you need.

If that filter is after the primary filter it could last a year or longer.  It looks like it has quite a few more months left in it.